# Replace img src for td img if has a class specific word

Tags: jquery

How can i use jQuery to find the td that has a certain text in the a class and have the img src replaced ?  Here is the HTML

```
<td>
 <img src="REPLACE IMG SOURCE WITH NEW IMAGE" class="headshot"></img>
 <a href="#" class="position_def">Rams, St. Louis STL Def</a>
</td>

<td>
 <img src="REPLACE IMG SOURCE WITH NEW IMAGE" class="headshot">
 <a href="#" class="position_def">Bengals, Cincinnati CIN Def</a>
</td>
```

I would like to locate td a , find text in the a class for "Rams" and replace that will a new img  , and also find "Bengals" and replace that img src too with yet another image different then the one for "Rams"

I tried this but it replaces the entire TD with a image

```
(function($) {
    var name = 'Rams';
    $('#divID').find('td').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == name; }).html( '<img src="MY NEW IMG" "class="detailsimg"/>' );
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Which part don't you know how to do?  Have you tried anything?  Also, it looks like you want to find text in an element, not in a class, right?

Comment: i can find the td but my attempt is replacing the entire td and not just the image src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code finds the `td` with the text, but then you use `.html()`, which applies to the found `td`.  Once you find the `td`, you want to filter for the `img` tag, and then change the `src` attribute:

```
var name = 'Rams';
$('#divID').find('td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().match(name); 
}).children('img').attr('src', "MY NEW IMG" );
```

Note, that using `==` won't generally work, due to the fact that `text()` returns all of the white space in the `td` tag.  `.match()`, or another matching/regex function will work much more reliably.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/1crbvr59/

Comment: I dont see where the specific text for each a class is in this? And since the img tags do not wrap the a tag , would this even work ?

Comment: Your HTML is not legal.  You cannot have `td`s without a `table` and `tr`s.  Also, using `==` won't work because `.text()` will return all of the white space in the entire `td`, so it won't match your string.  You want to use `.match()`.  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/nkcbkut8/

Comment: I print the contents of `.text()` to the console, so you can see that it has lots of extra white space.